# Detect CTRL click on PushButton

Tags: gwt

I'd like to detect when the <kbd>CRTL</kbd> key is pressed while clicking on a PushButton. The `ClickEvent.isControlKeyDown()` and `ClickEvent.getNativeEvent().getCtrlKey()` methods both return false on a click handler added to the PushButton regardless of whether the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is pressed or not.

How can I detect if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is pressed when the PushButton is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a `MouseDownHandler` like in

```
PushButton button = new PushButton("push");
button.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
        if (event.isControlKeyDown()) {
            Window.alert("test");
        }
    }
});
```

Guess that should work.